# Shopify polaris Use breadcrumbs component without Page

Tags: reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, polaris

Right now I'm using the `Page` component in shopify polaris with Reactjs. This component has a `breadcrumbs` property and it seems like you can only use breadcrumbs within the page component like this:

```
<Page
  breadcrumbs={[{content: 'Products', url: '/products'}]}
  title="Jar With Lock-Lid"
  primaryAction={{content: 'Save', disabled: true}}
  secondaryActions={[{content: 'Duplicate'}, {content: 'View on your store'}]}
  pagination={{
    hasPrevious: true,
    hasNext: true,
  }}
>
  <p>Page content</p>
</Page>
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to use breadcrumbs without using the Page component. Something like this:

```
<Breadcrumbs content: 'Products', url: '/products'/>
```

Any help with this would be great, thanks!

Comment: Ask Shopify. Polaris has a whole team, and a Github repo. You can ask them any question you want. Probably better than SO.